# Xampp php soap example with login that works local

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, xampp

I'm just tired and frustrated because I looked for some simple PHP and Soap examples but some were just too old so that the example wsdl file was missing, some didn't run etc.

So do you know any example for dummies that will even work in xampp and has a login?

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own wsdl file using php2wsdl lib and enable soap in your xampp by editing the php.ini file.